# Where have Mac Certificate trust settings gone?

Tags: macos, certificate, keychain

Greetings,

I am responsible for a Java Applet that needs to work on a wide range of Macs. This applet needs access to the file system and thus needs to be signed. On a Mac, even if the applet is signed and the certificate is valid, by default the applet will still not work. You need to open the certificate and put under the trust settings 'Always Trust'.

To know what I am talking about, see [mac docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Security/Conceptual/Security_Overview/Security_Services/Security_Services.html), 
Figure 3-3

Now, after installing the most recent update of Java on Macs, the trust section no longer appears and people who visit the site for the first time cannot get the applet to work any more. Any help, ideas, suggestion are very welcome.

T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fortunately no longer a problem on current OS X Lion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the original certificate (or one of the signing CAs in the certificate's path) is no longer valid.  Check dates of all of them in the whole cert path, not just that of the cert itself.